# Generic Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, multiple-inheritance

I have multiple controllers that have some common actions. I have made generic controllers:

```
 public class FirstBaseController<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IFirst, new()
 public class SecondBaseController<TEntity> where TEntity : class, ISecond, new()
```

Then i want to do something like this:

```
 public class MyController : FirstBaseController<First>, SecondBaseController<Second>
```

And I know that multiple class inheritance is not allowed in C#. Can you tell me alternative way to do this?

Comment: You can use generic interfaces. Multiple interface inheritance and implementing are allowed in C#.

Comment: You could also change from inheritance to composition. So rather than the controller "is a" it becomes "uses a"

Comment: Thanks to everybody for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option is to replace the base classes by interfaces and achieve reuse through composition:

```
public interface IMyFirstSetOfMethods<TEntity> { /*... */ }
public interface IMySecondSetOfMethods<TEntity> { /*... */}

public class FirstImpl 
{

}

public class SecondImpl
{
}


public class MyController : IMyFirstSetOfMethods<First> , IMySecondSetOfMethods<Second>
{
    FirstImpl myFirstImpl = new FirstImpl();
    SecondImpl mySecondImpl = new SecondImpl();

    // ... implement the methods from the interfaces by simply forwarding to the Impl classes
}
```